# Is there a way to set a font to apply to an entire email?

Tags: css, html-email

I've been trying to apply a font to an entire email (which is composed of a table).

Putting the font-family in the 'style' of the <body> tag doesn't work, nor does putting it in the <table> or <tbody> tags, nor does putting a <font> tag around the table work.

What is the best way to do this? Do I need a font-family inline style in each <td>, or a <font> tag around all of the content? Is there really no way to declare the font at an e-mail wide level?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to define your font in each `<td>`. Many email clients will automaticly reset the font within a `<td>`.

So something like `<td style='font-family: Arial'>`.

You can also do it in the header, but some clients will ignore this (looking at you outlook 2013-2016)
Body{
  font-family: Arial !important
}

Comment: I wish humanity would be able to render styled html in 2021. Seems like the cold fusion energy will come first.

Comment: @Meyhem, it seems cold fusion has already arrived and we still get unsupported `<style>` tags in some email clients.

Answer (score 1):

in your html/email put some style

```
<style type="text/css">
    td {font...;}
</style>
```

or generic using * instead of td

Comment: I would recommend against this, as some email clients (Gmail, for example) strips everything in the `head` of the html. For best results across all clients, use inline styles.

Comment: @xbonez well email clients are really a jungle, removed that header thing

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to apply the `font-family` to the table element, and all `td` elements will inherit that property, like this:

```
<table style="font-family: Courier">
<tr><td>Foo</td></tr>
<tr><td>Bar</td></tr>
</table>​
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/buaLR/5/)

This of course won't work if any `td` specifies its own `font-family` which will override the inherited value.

Comment: Thanks. I'm realizing that's what's happening. At least in Gmail, when I send the email, Gmail's CSS has a style for <code><td></code> that is overriding my table style. I guess I will need to put the style on each td?

Comment: You could try appending `!important` to give the style you specify for table more precedence, but I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: No luck - I believe that specificity trumps "!important", so styles applied to td still win.

Comment: Or rather, "!important" doesn't force inheriting, which isn't the same thing.  An `!important` rule on `*` would apply to the `td`s.